tsconfig lib setting for using WebAssembly in Node
Which tsconfig lib setting should I use for NodeJS so that Typescript knows about the WebAssembly object?
Node supports WebAssembly but not document:
> node
Welcome to Node.js v18.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> WebAssembly
Object [WebAssembly] {
  compile: [Function: compile],
  validate: [Function: validate],
  instantiate: [Function: instantiate],
  compileStreaming: [Function: compileStreaming],
  instantiateStreaming: [Function: instantiateStreaming]
}
>
> document
Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined
>

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to correspond to any lib setting. WebAssembly is in dom, but that also pulls in document. I'm a little surprised you can't use node. Am I missing something?
